# JS Value returning form all divs

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get first letter of firstname and lastname from a div and paste it in another div but it is pasting the same value in all divs and not taking unique value from each div.

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bv7w8dxg/1/

**Issue Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/bv7w8dxg/

```
 var takword = $('.nameholder').text().split(' ');
 var text = '';
 $.each(takword, function () {
    text += this.substring(0, 1);
 });
 $('.avatarholder').text(text);
```

Markup
     `
     John Doe

```
 <div class="main-holder">
 <div class="nameholder">Kyle Davis</div>
 <div class="avatarholder"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="main-holder">
 <div class="nameholder">Seim Seiy</div>
 <div class="avatarholder"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="main-holder">
<div class="nameholder">Momma Boy</div>
<div class="avatarholder"></div>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using class selectors, which selects all elements with the given class name. That's why you have all the elements set with same value

You need to wrap your elements then process each row independently
I updated your code snippet to demonstrate this:

```js
$('.row').each(function() {
  var takword = $('.nameholder', this).text().split(' ');
  var text = '';
  $.each(takword, function () {
      text += this.substring(0, 1);
  });
  $('.avatarholder', this).text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="nameholder">John Doe</div>
  <div class="avatarholder"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="nameholder">Kyle Davis</div>
  <div class="avatarholder"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="nameholder">Seim Seiy</div>
  <div class="avatarholder"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="nameholder">Momma Boy</div>
  <div class="avatarholder"></div>
</div>
```